# Do I need to call removeObserver for lifecycle, upon its onDestroy() event?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-architecture-lifecycle

This is a very simple question:

### Background

I'm using the relatively new [**Lifecycle class**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle) (part of the [**android architecture components libraries**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/arch/)) to handle some events of the `Activity/Fragment` in an easier way.

This is how you use it for handling [**ON_DESTROY**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Lifecycle.Event#ON_DESTROY) event:

```
            lifecycle.addObserver(object : LifecycleObserver {
                @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
                fun onDestroy() {
                    lifecycle.removeObserver(this)
                    //Do something
                }
            })
```

### The problem

I can't find in the [**docs**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle#lc) and here, whether I should call `removeObserver` or that it's done automatically anyway upon the [**ON_DESTROY**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Lifecycle.Event#ON_DESTROY) event.

### What I've tried

I tried to read about it, and for now as a precaution I always call `removeObserver` .

### The question

Is it safe to avoid calling `removeObserver` upon [**ON_DESTROY**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Lifecycle.Event#ON_DESTROY) event?

Comment: AFAIK , no need to call `removeObserve` explicitly. https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-lifecycles/issues/5

Comment: @Radhey Why not put it in an answer so that I could accept it? Seems they wrote that it's not needed on this case...

Comment: I should not get credit of another developers solution. still if you want then I can do it so other community member can take proper readable solution :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is one chain of discussion over github related this topic.

As far as I know, there is no need to call `removeObserve` explicitly.

The only reason is that lifecycle-aware components are specifically designed to make sure the observer is removed.

Here is the link to where this is discussed: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-lifecycles/issues/5

Answer (score -1):

In my point, if you call `lifecycle.addObserver` in application, you don't have to call `removeObserver`, when the application is destroyed, the process would be killed also. If you call `lifecycle.addObserver` in an activity, you need to call `removeObserver` on `OnDestroy` method.